# Docker compose - mysql mount volume empty

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I mounted local drive as volume for mysql Docker image:

```
mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:dev
    build: ./mysql
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD : ${DB_PASSWORD}
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - ./../mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

After `docker-compose up`, local folder in host machine is empty

Docker inspect:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "d8681e2af542638dc47c0a04cdd8dc7cb680e2452d63383a43335062ba31a8cb",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d8681e2af542638dc47c0a04cdd8dc7cb680e2452d63383a43335062ba31a8cb/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
```

Docker host is Windows 10 machine, Docker desktop is running, empty folder is created, but no mysql data in it

In container there are data in `/var/lib/mysql` but it's not shown on local folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Restarted Docker for Desktop
- Relaunched editor (Visual studio code) as Administrator
- deleted mysql containers and images
- `docker-compose up -d --build`

Local folder is automatically populated

[image]